# Segmentation fault when passing by pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Problem: Original problem is to add 2 Numbers stored as linked list(Each digit stored in a node). Tried to print nodes of linked list. But throwing segmentation fault when passing to "Print()". But Print() works the first 2 times (Am i just getting lucky here?).(Note: The code is messy, since I am trying different things to learn C++. And I do not have any experience with valgrind so i might not be using the correct options in the command).

Tried cout statements to locate where SIGSEGV is thrown.
Tried using Valgrind to get some more info. Noticed more errors.
 
Namely:
    1.Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    2.Use of uninitialised value of size
    3.Invalid read of size

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int digit;
    Node *next;
    Node(int d): digit(d) { next = NULL;}
    Node(){}
};

struct Node* head1;
struct Node* head2;
struct Node* s;

void insert(struct Node* &head, struct Node &node){
    struct Node* temp; 
    temp = new Node(node.digit);
    //(*temp).digit = node.digit;
    if(head != NULL){
        temp->next = head;
    }
    head = temp;
}

void print(struct Node* head){
    cout<<"Print: "<<endl;
    while(head!=NULL){
        cout<<head->digit;
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

struct Node* add(struct Node* head1, struct Node* head2){
    struct Node* sum;
    int carry = 0;
    while(head1!=NULL && head2!=NULL){
        int x = head1->digit + head2 ->digit + carry;
        carry = x/10;
        x = x%10;
        struct Node t(x);
        insert(sum,t);
        head1 = head1 -> next;
        head2 = head2 -> next;
    }
    while(head1!=NULL){
        struct Node t((head1->digit)+carry);
        carry=0;
        insert(sum,t);
        head1 = head1 -> next;
    }
    while(head2!=NULL){
        struct Node t((head2->digit)+carry);
        carry=0;
        insert(sum,t);
        head2 = head2 -> next;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){

    int n1,n2,t;
    cout<<"Enter no. of digits in 1st, 2nd number"<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    cin>>n2;

    cout<<"Enter digits of no 1:"<<endl;
    while(n1>0){
        cout<<"Enter digit at "<<n1<<":"<<endl;
        cin>>t;//Have to check if single digit
        struct Node temp(t);
        insert(head1, temp);
        n1--;
    }
    cout<<"no1(rev):"<<endl;
    print(head1);//Not throwing Error!!!

    cout<<"Enter digits of no 2:"<<endl;
    while(n2>0){
        cout<<"Enter digit at "<<n2<<":"<<endl;
        cin>>t;//Have to check if single digit
        struct Node temp(t);
        insert(head2,temp);
        n2--;
    }
    cout<<"no2(rev):"<<endl;
    print(head2);//Not throwing Error!!!

    cout<<"sum"<<endl;
    s = add(head1,head2);
    cout<<"Verifying s is sum:";
    cout<<s->digit;
    cout<<s->next->digit;
    cout<<s->next->next->digit;
    cout<<s->next->next->next->digit;
    cout<<endl;
    print(s);// This is throwing Error!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output using valgrind:

```
> valgrind --leak-check=yes ./LinkedListAdd.out
> 
> ==8070== Memcheck, a memory error detector
> ==8070== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
> ==8070== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
> ==8070== Command: ./LinkedListAdd.out
> ==8070==  
> Enter no. of digits in 1st, 2nd number 
> 3 4 
> Enter digits of no 1:             
> Enter digit at 3: 
> 5 
> Enter digit at 2: 
> 6 
> Enter digit at 1: 
> 7
> no1(rev): 
> Print:  
> 765 
> Enter digits of no 2: 
> Enter digit at 4: 
> 5 
> Enter digit at 3: 
> 6 
> Enter digit at 2: 
> 7 
> Enter digit at 1: 
> 8 
> no2(rev): 
> Print: 
> 8765 
> sum
> ==8070== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==8070==    at 0x4009B9: insert(Node*&, Node&) (LinkedListAdd.cpp:20)
> ==8070==    by 0x400AD2: add(Node*, Node*) (LinkedListAdd.cpp:43)
> ==8070==    by 0x400D92: main (LinkedListAdd.cpp:92)
> ==8070==  
> Verifying s is sum:6245 
> Print: 
> ==8070== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==8070==    at 0x400A29: print(Node*) (LinkedListAdd.cpp:28)
> ==8070==    by 0x400E32: main (LinkedListAdd.cpp:99)
> ==8070== 
> ==8070== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==8070==    at 0x400A0A: print(Node*) (LinkedListAdd.cpp:29)
> ==8070==    by 0x400E32: main (LinkedListAdd.cpp:99)
> ==8070== 
> ==8070== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==8070==    at 0x400A1C: print(Node*) (LinkedListAdd.cpp:30)
> ==8070==    by 0x400E32: main (LinkedListAdd.cpp:99)
> ==8070== 
> ==8070== Invalid read of size 4
> ==8070==    at 0x400A0A: print(Node*) (LinkedListAdd.cpp:29)
> ==8070==    by 0x400E32: main (LinkedListAdd.cpp:99)
> ==8070==  Address 0x750000800003f7da is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
> ==8070== 
> ==8070== 
> ==8070== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
> ==8070==  General Protection Fault
> ==8070==    at 0x400A0A: print(Node*) (LinkedListAdd.cpp:29)
> ==8070==    by 0x400E32: main (LinkedListAdd.cpp:99) 6245-1064971727==8070== 
> ==8070== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==8070==     in use at exit: 176 bytes in 11 blocks
> ==8070==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 0 frees, 176 bytes allocated
> ==8070== 
> ==8070== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==8070==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==8070==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==8070==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==8070==    still reachable: 176 bytes in 11 blocks
> ==8070==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==8070== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
> ==8070== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
> ==8070== 
> ==8070== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==8070== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
> ==8070== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0) Segmentation fault
```

Please help me understand what might be going wrong / direct me to resources that might help me understand.

Comment: Why build your own linked list when `std::list` already exists? And why use a linked list at all? It's a very inefficient datastructure on modern CPUs - usually you would want a `std::vector`.

Comment: "Tried cout statements to locate where SIGSEGV is thrown." - You should try using your debugger instead.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the only place where you need to write `struct Node` is the first time, when you define the struct. Everywhere else it can be just `Node`. (C requires `struct Node`, unless you do the typedef dance)

Comment: Hi @JesperJuhl I tried using valgrind when i realized that cout's arent of much help. Couldnt makeput much from valgrinds output either. The purpose of using my own linkedlist is just for practice/learning.

Comment: @sdnemina Valgrind is not a debugger. Run your program in a debugger and step through it line by line; observing control flow and variable values and the stack trace as you go along. Then spotting your bug should become obvious. Learning to use a debugger is an *essential* skill.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ok I will try using a debugger :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize the `sum` pointer:

```
struct Node* add(struct Node* head1, struct Node* head2){
    struct Node* sum;   // <<<<< uninitialized
    ...
    while(head1!=NULL && head2!=NULL){
        ...
        insert(sum,t);  // <<<<< undefined behaviour within
```

(There may be other problems, but that's the most obvious one.)

Comment: when i am passing sum in insert, i am passing reference to pointer, within insert i am initializing temp and then assigning the reference to temp. Isn't that the same thing? Or is there something wrong with my understanding of how things are working in my code.

Comment: @sdnemina: In practical terms, you start with `sum` containing a random pointer. `insert` then copies that random pointer into the new node's `next` field.

Comment: I think i got it now. Thanks

Comment: Any idea why when i print values in s to verify it works but when i pass s to print it throws the error?